# What creates more dveikus, tefillah or learning?

Tags: tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study

I have heard that learning Torah is what makes a person "closer" to God, so to speak. I have also heard that Tefillah does this. I am using the word dveikus very loosely as I am sure there are very specific explanations as to what it means to be davuk to Hashem.

I would like to know, according to the sources, what creates 'more dveikus', tefillah or learning Torah?

Comment: How is this measured?

Comment: @rosends presumably in the fundamental units of *dveikus*. We could call it the *dveikon*.

Comment: I translate *dveikut* as "devotion" or, perhaps, better "perseverance". If you were to follow the 2nd definition, this could be quantitatively measured by tracking how much time during the day, e.g. one performs either task. Considering that the time allotted for prayer is a fraction of the time available during the day, and the rest of the time should be largely devoted to learning Torah (minus personal needs such as eating, rest room breaks, and rest, etc.) it seems that learning Torah would yield far more "dveikut".

Comment: Presumably the closeness is a result of ones intent and thoughts. If one mutters a couple words of prayer it is hard to imagine that the same degree of closeness is achieved as one who offers a heartfelt prayer. Accordingly, it seems difficult to speak of prayer or study in the abstract regarding coming close to God (whatever that means), since presumably it isn't the act itself; but the associated thoughts.

Comment: Editing in some source that Torah study does any of this would improve the question.

Comment: @RobertColumbia besides dveikon, there could also be a type of unit that allows a qualitative dveikus that other units do not. Sort of like needing to buy the better kind of tokens to get onto the better rides at an amusement park. (Also, how did you italicize in the comments?!)